# How to detect process set with CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP and why GetConsoleProcessList(..) return process with CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE flag?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, windows-7

I am trying to emulate `SIGTERM` in windows using `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(..)`. I read the condition should be that the new process be in a new process group and share the console of the calling process.  In connection to this work, I have two questions -

1. Given a process id,  is it possible to determine using any current windows API if the process is created with `CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP` flag?
2. `GetConsoleProcessList(..)` gives me all process belonging to the console of the calling process including the one created with `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` flag. This looked like a surprise, so can someone clarify the meaning of it?

Comment: (1) No function exists to determine the console process group ID. (2) The console host is buggy if we call `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent` on a child process that's doesn't share our console. It adds a broken entry to its process list and keeps a handle for the process that it never closes. This not only corrupts the process list, but it also breaks subsequent calls to `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent`.